# Why does my script in Python 2.7 only give geocode output for one row instead of the entire dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, time, geocoding

Im working out of Python 2.7 version. I have a csv file with +5k addresses in the form:

```
df.head(10)




  Out[19]: 
                    ADDRESS STATE  ZIP_CODE
    0    2577 Long Bow Ave     OH     43130
    1     4822 Armandale Nw    OH     44718
    2     348 Grandview Ave    NJ      8837
    3        81 Rhoades Ave    MA      2032
    4  296 Monte Cristo Dr.    NV     89403
    5       4348 9th Street    AK     99703
    6  5649 Vera Cruz Ave N    MN     55429
    7      1104 N Modoc Ave    OR     97504
    8    12 Division Avenue    NY     10977
    9     69 Washington Ave    NJ      7642
```

## My code:

```
import geocoder
import requests
import time
import pandas as pd


# ----------------------------- CONFIGURATION -----------------------------#

# Set the input and output files
input_file_path = "geocodi.csv"
output_file_path = "output"  # appends "####.csv" to the file name when it writes the file.

# Set the name of the column indexes here so that pandas can read the CSV file
address_column_name = "ADDRESS"
state_column_name = "STATE"
zip_column_name = "ZIP_CODE"   # Leave blank("") if you do not have zip codes

# Where the program starts processing the addresses in the input file
# This is useful in case the computer crashes so you can resume the program where it left off or so you can run multiple
# instances of the program starting at different spots in the input file
start_index = 0
# How often the program prints the status of the running program
status_rate = 100
# How often the program saves a backup file
write_data_rate = 1000
# How many times the program tries to geocode an address before it gives up
attempts_to_geocode = 3
# Time it delays each time it does not find an address
# Note that this is added to itself each time it fails so it should not be set to a large number
wait_time = 3

# ----------------------------- Processing the input file -----------------------------#

df = pd.read_csv(input_file_path, low_memory=False)
# df = pd.read_excel(input_file_path)

# Raise errors if the provided column names could not be found in the input file
if address_column_name not in df.columns:
    raise ValueError("Can't find the address column in the input file.")
if state_column_name not in df.columns:
    raise ValueError("Can't find the state column in the input file.")

# Zip code is not needed but helps provide more accurate locations
if (zip_column_name):
    if zip_column_name not in df.columns:
        raise ValueError("Can't find the zip code column in the input file.")
    addresses = (df[address_column_name] + ', ' + df[zip_column_name].astype(str) + ', ' + df[state_column_name]).tolist()
else:
    addresses = (df[address_column_name] + ', ' + df[state_column_name]).tolist()


# ----------------------------- Function Definitions -----------------------------#

# Creates request sessions for geocoding
class GeoSessions:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Arcgis = requests.Session()
        self.Komoot = requests.Session()


# Class that is used to return 3 new sessions for each geocoding source
def create_sessions():
    return GeoSessions()


# Main geocoding function that uses the geocoding package to covert addresses into lat, longs
def geocode_address(address, s):
    g = geocoder.arcgis(address, session=s.Arcgis)
    if (g.ok == False):
        g = geocoder.komoot(address, session=s.Komoot)

    return g


def try_address(address, s, attempts_remaining, wait_time):
    g = geocode_address(address, s)
    if (g.ok == False):
        time.sleep(wait_time)
        s = create_sessions()  # It is not very likely that we can't find an address so we create new sessions and wait
        if (attempts_remaining > 0):
            try_address(address, s, attempts_remaining-1, wait_time+wait_time)
    return g


# Function used to write data to the output file
def write_data(data, index):
    file_name = (output_file_path + str(index) + ".csv")
    print("Created the file: " + file_name)
    done = pd.DataFrame(data)
    done.columns = ['Address', 'Lat', 'Long', 'Provider']
    done.to_csv((file_name + ".csv"), sep=',', encoding='utf8')


# Variables used in the main for loop that do not need to be modified by the user
s = create_sessions()
results = []
failed = 0
total_failed = 0
progress = len(addresses) - start_index

# ----------------------------- Main Loop -----------------------------#

for i, address in enumerate(addresses[start_index:]):
    # Print the status of how many addresses have be processed so far and how many of the failed.
    if ((start_index + i) % status_rate == 0):
        total_failed += failed
        print(
            "Completed {} of {}. Failed {} for this section and {} in total.".format(i + start_index, progress, failed,
                                                                                     total_failed))
        failed = 0

    # Try geocoding the addresses
    try:
        g = try_address(address, s, attempts_to_geocode, wait_time)
        if (g.ok == False):
            results.append([address, "was", "not", "geocoded"])
            print("Gave up on address: " + address)
            failed += 1
        else:
            results.append([address, g.latlng[0], g.latlng[1], g.provider])

    # If we failed with an error like a timeout we will try the address again after we wait 5 secs
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed with error {} on address {}. Will try again.".format(e, address))
        try:
            time.sleep(5)
            s = create_sessions()
            g = geocode_address(address, s)
            if (g.ok == False):
                print("Did not fine it.")
                results.append([address, "was", "not", "geocoded"])
                failed += 1
            else:
                print("Successfully found it.")
                results.append([address, g.latlng[0], g.latlng[1], g.provider])
        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed with error {} on address {} again.".format(e, address))
            failed += 1
            results.append([address, e, e, "ERROR"])

    # Writing what has been processed so far to an output file
    if (i%write_data_rate == 0 and i != 0):
        write_data(results, i + start_index)

    # print(i, g.latlng, g.provider)


# Finished
write_data(results, i + start_index + 1)
print("Finished! :)")
```

The whole script works without any bugs or stalling, but only the last rows data is pulled out in the output file. Why does this happen? Even though it is going through the entire file and all the rows? Please note this is Python 2.7 version

Comment: Please show the definition of `write_data()` which you call twice inside and outside loop.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue... I ran your code above with a list of 30 addresses, and I received 30 addresses in my geocoded output file.The index value in the first column is zero indexed, so the last value is 29.